# Check text field value with database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to check inserting username is correct or not using jquery and php.. if username is not match with the value from database, it should be trigger an alert saying 'your user name is wrong'.

I tried this but I couldn't figure this out. When I type an username alert message triggering for each letter. But I need to check given value with database after entering in text field.

This is my Jquery -

```
    // --- Check Username Availability for successful login --- //
    $('#loginusername').keyup(function() {
      var checkname=$(this).val();
      var availname=remove_whitespaces(checkname);
      if(availname!=''){
         var String = 'username='+ availname;

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "emailCheck.php",
                data: String,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    var result=remove_whitespaces(result);
                    if(result == $('#loginusername').val()){
                        alert('Your entered Username is ok');                           
                    } else {
                        alert('Your entered Username is wrong');                                                            
                    }
                }
            });
      }
   });
```

This is from emailCheck.php

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
   $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['username']);

    $q = "SELECT username FROM userlogin 
            WHERE username = '$userName'";
   $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

   $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);

    $HTML='';
   if($count == 1){
      $HTML='username exists';
   }else{
      $HTML='';
   }

    echo $HTML;
}
```

Comment: Where does your code stop working? Is the .keyup called?

Comment: Instead of binding the check to the `keyup` event you could bind it to the `change` event which is fired once you leave that input field.

Comment: @cars10 I tried it using `change`. then its always going to else part of ajax success function.

Comment: When you send data with POST you have to include it in object format like `data: {username:availname}`, sending the string `'username='+ availname` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `keyup` event of textbox, use `blur` OR `change` event of textbox.

**Edit**

Change

```
 if(result == $('#loginusername').val())
```

to

```
 if(result == '')
```

Because you are sending blank result when no match found.

Comment: I tried both `blur` and `change`. But it is always going to else part of the ajax success function. And also tried using `alert(result)` in else part of success function. Then alerting 'username exist' string.

Comment: Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your JS, you're comparing what the user entered to what the PHP script returns:

```
result == $('#loginusername').val()
```

But the only thing your PHP script can return is the string 'username exists' or an empty string:

```
if($count == 1){
  $HTML='username exists';
}else{
  $HTML='';
}
```

Try just using `alert(result)`.

Comment: I tried using `alert(result)` in else part of ajax success function, then it is alerting 'username existing' string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;
var time = 2000; 
$('input').keyup(function() {
  // when user stop typing for {time} second, do next function
  timer= setTimeout(doSomething, time); 
)
$('input').keydown(function() {
  // when user continue typing clear timer
  clearTimeout(timer);
)
function doSomething() {

}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Change `echo $HTML;` to `echo '{"success":"true", "usernameExists":"' + $count + '"}';`
Then amend your Javascript to this

...

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "emailCheck.php",
                data: {username: availname},
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    if(result.usernameExists == 1){
                        alert('Your entered Username is ok');                           
                    } else {
                        alert('Your entered Username is wrong');                                                            
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using keyup use 'onchange'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.blur` trigger. http://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
// --- Check Username Availability for successful login --- //
$('#loginusername').blur(function() {
  var checkname=$(this).val();
  var availname=remove_whitespaces(checkname);
  if(availname!=''){
     var String = 'username='+ availname;

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "emailCheck.php",
            data: String,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                var result=remove_whitespaces(result);
                if(result == $('#loginusername').val()){
                    alert('Your entered Username is ok');                           
                } else {
                    alert('Your entered Username is wrong');                                                            
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should change the event that your firing your check code. right now your firing at every `keyup`. I suggest change this to `change`

```
$('#loginusername').change(function() {
```

second there is an issue with your json response. In your php side your responding with an empty string when username is not found and an error message when the username is found. But your javascript side is expecting the return value to be the same as the username the user typed in the textbox when the string is available.

To meet this requirement lets change your php side of the code.

```
 $HTML='';
   if($count == 1){
      $HTML='username exists';
   }else{
      $HTML=$_POST['username'];
   }
```